# How to specify whether a connector is a source or a sink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am currently configuring kafka connect (with [debezium/connect docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect)), I successfully connected it to Kafka using environment variables:

```
docker run -it --rm --name AAAAAA-kafka-connect -p 8083:8083 \
    -v aaaaa.jks:aaaaa.jks \
    -v bbbbbb.jks:bbbbbb.jks \
    -e LOG_LEVEL=INFO \
    -e HOST_NAME="AAAAAA-kafka-connect" \
    -e HEAP_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2g" \
    -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="BBBBB:9092" \
    -e CONNECT_CLIENT_ID="xxx-kafka-connect" \
    -e CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG="org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"...\" password=\"...\";" \
    -e CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL="SASL_SSL" \
    -e CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM="PLAIN" \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION="bbbbbb.jks" \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD="..." \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION="aaaaa.jks" \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="..." \
    -e GROUP_ID="XXX.grp.kafka.connect" \
    -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="XXX.connect.configs.v1" \
    -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="XXX.connect.offsets.v1" \
    -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="XXX.connect.statuses.v1" \
    quay.io/debezium/connect:1.9
```

Now I have to create a source connector (`posgresql db`) and I want the data kafka connect will grab from the source to be sink in a kafka topic.

Where do I have to set the kafka configuration of the sink since there is no such config in the json config of the database connector?

Have I to create a sink connector to the kafka topic? if so, where do we specify if this is a sink or a source connector??

PS: I already have created the kafka topic where i want to put datas in

Feel free to ask questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, you have to add the `CONNECT_PRODUCER_*` or `CONNECT_CONSUMER_*` environment variables to specify the config of source or sink !!!!!!

Like this:

```
docker run -it --rm --name AAAAAA-kafka-connect -p 8083:8083 \
    -v aaaaa.jks:aaaaa.jks \
    -v bbbbbb.jks:bbbbbb.jks \
    -e LOG_LEVEL=INFO \
    -e HOST_NAME="AAAAAA-kafka-connect" \
    -e HEAP_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx2g" \
    -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="BBBBB:9092" \
    -e CONNECT_CLIENT_ID="xxx-kafka-connect" \
    -e CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG="org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"...\" password=\"...\";" \
    -e CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL="SASL_SSL" \
    -e CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM="PLAIN" \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION="bbbbbb.jks" \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD="..." \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION="aaaaa.jks" \
    -e CONNECT_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="..." \
    -e GROUP_ID="XXX.grp.kafka.connect" \
    -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="XXX.connect.configs.v1" \
    -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="XXX.connect.offsets.v1" \
    -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="XXX.connect.statuses.v1" \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE=false \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG="org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"...\" password=\"...\";" \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL="SASL_SSL" \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM="PLAIN" \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION="bbbbbb.jks" \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD="..." \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION="aaaaa.jks" \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="..." \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_CLIENT_ID="xxx-kafka-connect" \
    -e CONNECT_PRODUCER_TOPIC_CREATION_ENABLE=false \
    quay.io/debezium/connect:1.9
```

the `sink` or `source` property comes from the `connector.class` used in the json definition of the connector.  However, Debeziums CDC connectors can only be used as a source connector that captures real-time event change records from external database systems ([https://hevodata.com/learn/debezium-vs-kafka-connect/#:~:text=Debezium%20platform%20has%20a%20vast,records%20from%20external%20database%20systems.](https://hevodata.com/learn/debezium-vs-kafka-connect/#:%7E:text=Debezium%20platform%20has%20a%20vast,records%20from%20external%20database%20systems.))

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables only modify the client parameters.

Source and Sinks are determined when you actually create the connector. You need a JSON config and it will have a `connector.class`.

In Kafka API there is [`SinkTask`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/sink/SinkTask.html) and [`SourceTask`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/source/SourceTask.html).

Debezium is **always** a Source. Sources write to Kafka; that doesn't make Kafka a sink. You need to install a new connector plugin to get a sink *for your database*, such as the JDBC Connector from Confluent which has classes for both sources and sinks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact the CONNECT_XXX modify the client (Kafka connect right?) But the CONNECT_PRODUCER_XXX modify the connector config, in fact I got the JSON to create the source postgres database connector. However I know that there is a first connection to Kafka for the kafka-connect configurations topic, but for the db as a source have I to create another JSON connector for Kafka as a sink :0?

Comment: No. Connect wraps internal producer and consumer clients. These properties are inserted into `connect-distributed.properties` file, which is used by all workers. You still need to submit a worker configuration. And again "as sink" is not proper terminology when _reading from a database_. You will need another config to **write** to a database sink